# View with a map subview bounced back to its caller when kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cllocationmanager

Here I have 2 views:

- LoginViewController
- WallViewController

After user login in **LoginViewController**, it will go to **WallViewController** which contains a map view. First it will ask user permission to access current location. If user chooses to allow the access, there will not be any problem. However, if user chooses NOT to allow the access, user will be bounced from **WallViewController** back to **LoginViewController**. **What I would like to do is to have user remain in WallViewController even though current location cannot be accessed. How can I achieve that?** Here below is my relevant code.

**LoginViewController.m**

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    // Tear down the activity view in all cases.
    [activityView.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityView removeFromSuperview];

    if (user) {
        //***************call WallViewController here*********
        PAWWallViewController *wallViewController = [[PAWWallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController pushViewController:wallViewController animated:NO];
        [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //****************************************************

    } else {
        // Didn't get a user.
        NSLog(@"%s didn't get a user!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        // Re-enable the done button if we're tossing them back into the form.
        doneButton.enabled = [self shouldEnableDoneButton];
        UIAlertView *alertView2 = nil;

        if (error == nil) {
            // the username or password is probably wrong.
            NSLog(@"1");
            alertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Couldn’t log in:\nThe username or password were wrong.", nil) message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil), nil];
            alertView2.tag = kSecondAlertViewTag;
        } else {
            // Something else went horribly wrong:
            NSLog(@"2");
            alertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil), nil];
            alertView2.tag = kSecondAlertViewTag;
        }
        [alertView2 show];
        // Bring the keyboard back up, because they'll probably need to change something.
        [usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}];
```

**WallViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    [self startStandardUpdates];
}

- (void)startStandardUpdates {
    if (nil == locationManager) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    locationManager.delegate = self;

    // This part was added due to a location authorization issue on iOS8
    // See more at: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/
    if ([self._locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self._locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
    if (currentLocation) {
        PAWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
            // Re-enable the post button if it was disabled before.
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        //**********This alert will show up, once click Ok it will go back to its caller which is LoginViewController***********
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied");
            {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"This app can’t access your current location.\n\nTo view nearby posts or create a post at your current location, turn on access for this app to your location in the Settings app under Location Services.", nil) message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil), nil];
                [alertView show];
                // Disable the post button.
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;    
            }
            break;
        //**********************************************************************************************************************

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
            break;
        default:break;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    PAWAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.currentLocation = newLocation;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);

    if (error.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    } else if (error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
        // todo: retry?
        // set a timer for five seconds to cycle location, and if it fails again, bail and tell the user.
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error retrieving location", nil)
                                                    message:[error description]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil), nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Given the above code, what I found after login is that there will be a popup asking whether user allows current location access. If user chooses No, there will be an alert view saying *"This app can’t access your current location. To view nearby posts or create a post at your current location, turn on access for this app to your location in the Settings app under Location Services."* After I click Ok, it will go back to its caller which is **LoginViewController** but I want it to remain in **WallViewController**. Need some helps here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So in WallViewController viewDidLoad, are you doing anything else? It seems like somewhere you must be popping to the root view controller or something

Comment: Yes there's something else but none could be popping to the root VC. What I understand is that once status falls into the case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied the current view (WallViewController) will be forced to dismiss then go back to the root view LoginViewController. I cannot find a way to prevent that. If you have any clue, please advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `delegate:self` to `delegate:nil` in the below code and it solved the issue.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"This app can’t access your current location.\n\nTo view nearby posts or create a post at your current location, turn on access for this app to your location in the Settings app under Location Services.", nil) message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil), nil];
```